# How to clip an array to the minimum and maximum without using loops

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am still learning python, and I am writing a code to clip an array to the minimum and the maximum value, but without using any loops.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def clip(array, minimum, maximum):
    return None

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

minimum = input ("Enter your minimum value")
maximum = input ("Enter your maximum value")

# min = minimum
# max = maximum

# mean = (min + max)/2

result_arr = clip(array, minimum, maximum)
print (result_arr)
plt.plot(array, result_arr)
plt.show()
```

But I still does not show the result plot. What do I need to fix?

Comment: your clip function returns `None` so it is expected that nothing works. What do you mean by clipping, you want to normalize to min/max?

Comment: For example:
if my array is [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 clipped to a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 6 should give
[3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6]

Comment: You may use `numpy` bu tin theory it uses loops too. You might use `map`. I'm not sure if `map` uses loops or not. But most probably it uses.

Comment: @Sherwet ok then use `np.clip`, don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: I did that, but the minimum and the maximum values could change, but whenever I initiate them the error "missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a_min' and 'a_max'" shows when I have two variables min and max

Comment: You have created `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, but this is a `list`, not an array. An array is a numpy object. A `np.array` and a `list` have different properties / methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) as mozway suggested.

---

### The `clip` function

First, we import the required libraries.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And then, simply define the `clip` function that takes the minimum and the maximum values from the user's input.

```py
def clip(array):
    min_val, max_val = [
        float(input(i))
        for i in ["Minimum value: ", "Maximum value: "]
    ]

    return np.clip(array, min_val, max_val)
```

---

### Output

We will test our `clip` function on a sample array.

```py
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> clip(a)

Minimum value: 3
Maximum value: 8

array([3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8])
```

---

### Plotting

We will define an arbitrary array with [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

```py
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
x_values = np.arange(len(a))
```

Finally, we clip and plot the two arrays as follows.

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(9, 3),
                               tight_layout=True, dpi=144)

ax1.plot(x, a)
ax1.set_title("Unclipped Array")

ax2.plot(x, clip(a))
ax2.set_title("Clipped Array")

plt.show()
```

```py
Minimum value: 25
Maximum value: 75
```

[image: Visualization]

The above plot is our final result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your "clipping" should do, here's some idea with "native python" i.e no imports (can be done otherwise using e.g `numpy` or `pandas.Series`):

```py
#Remove all elements outside [mi,ma]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
mi = 3 #min
ma = 7  #max
list(filter(lambda x: mi<x<ma,a)) # [4,5,6]
```

```py
#Set elements greater than 7 to 7 and all elements less than 3 to three
def clip_to_min_max(x,mi,max):
   if x<mi: #Number is less than "mi" set it to "mi"
      return mi
   if x>ma: #Number is greater han "max", set it to "ma"
      return mx
   return x #It is between "mi" and "ma" - do nothing

[clip_to_min_max(x,3,7) for x in  a] #[3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7]
```